# How to install OpenLDAP password check module in ubuntu?

Tags: passwords, ldap, ubuntu-14.04, openldap

We recently installed ppolicy module and the related things in our OpenLDAP instance for password policy ( http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html#account-unlock) . However, among them there was no way to set up something that does a password check whenever a new password is set. Then, we were pointed out to this link - http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/openldap-ppolicy-check-password , where pwdPolicyChecker seemed like a module that can solve this issue. But we have no idea how to install this C module in our current ubuntu OpenLDAP set up. Also, the instructions provided seemed to be more like how the openldap setup used to be earlier in ubuntu and not like how it is now with slapd.d . Has anyone done an installation of a C module in OpenLDAP in the new ubuntu setup? Any pointers toward that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: May I suggest you don't do this? LDAP is a mission-critical service and you really shouldn't be polluting it with your own code. The password policy module is already pretty powerful.

Comment: I surely wouldn't mind doing it but I couldn't find anything in password policy module that can do something like this for our use case of setting up a password check. If there is something there, I would be more than happy to use it instead of going for some external thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the LTB's pwdCheckerModule for years without a glitch.

I just rebuilt it - as a package, for Debian/Stretch - using the tweaked Onyx Point's version; https://github.com/onyxpoint/ppolicy-check-password

I created the corresponding Debian-specific fork - https://github.com/cedric-dufour/ppolicy-check-password/tree/debian-stretch - including the README.DEBIAN file that should answer your question (most relevant part copied below); doing the same for Ubuntu should not be too different.

```
 * Get the Debian source code for the OpenLDAP packages and build dependencies:

   apt-get source openldap
   apt-get build-deps openldap

 * Include the ppolicy-check-password source code into the OpenLDAP source tree
   and install additional build dependencies:

   cd openldap-<version>
   mkdir -p contrib/slapd-modules/ppolicy-check-password
   cp /path/to/ppolicy-check-password.git/* contrib/slapd-modules/ppolicy-check-password/.
   apt-get install libcrack2-dev

 * Patch the Debian (packaging) directory:

   patch -p1 < /path/to/ppolicy-check-password.git/debian/debian-directory.patch

 * Build the OpenLDAP packages:

   dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b

 * Copy and install the slapd-ppolicy-check-password_<version>.deb package to
   the target server:

   dpkg -i slapd-ppolicy-check-password_<version>.deb

 * Configure the ppolicy-check-password module:

   vim /etc/ldap/check_password.conf

 * Add the ppolicy-check-password module/check to your PPolicy:

   pwdCheckModule: check_password.so
   pwdCheckQuality: 2
```